# Twine Installation error in Termux Android app

Tags: python, twine

I want to install **twine** module in ***Termux*** Android app. But I found this error. Screenshot bellow.
`
If you did intend to build this package f rom source, try installing a Rust compiler from your system package manager and ensure it is on the PATH d uring installation. Alternatively, rustup (available at https://rustup.rs) is the recommended way to downl oad and update the Rust compiler toolchain.

[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess and is likely not a problem with pip.

ERROR: Failed building wheel for maturin

Failed to build maturin

ERROR: Could not build wheels for maturin, h is required to install pyproject.toml-based project

S

[end of output1

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

error: subprocess-exited-with-error

- pip subprocess to install build dependencies did no t run successfully.

exit code: 1

See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
`
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odb5T.png)

How to fix this error and install **twine** module?

Please Help Me to fix this error?